# Dynamically use different class depending on current namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, yii2

I would like my class to inherit methods off of its parent, I've done this by extending the class. But i would also like to instantiate a class using the basename(without namespace) and have the correct class be instantiate, chosen based on the current namespace and then fall back to a 'common' class if it doesn't exist.

example

```
<?php

namespace common\models {


    class Account extends Model{}
    class Orders extends Model{}

    class Customer extends Model{

        use common\models\Account;

        public static function getAccountClass(){
            echo get_class(new Account());
        }
        public static function getOrdersClass(){
            echo get_class(new Order());
        }
    }
}


namespace frontend\models {

    class Account extends common\models\Account {}

    class Customer extends common\models\customer {

    }
}
```

I would like the `common\models\Customer::getAccountClass()` to output `common\models\Account`

and

`frontend\models\Customer::getAccountClass()` to output `frontend\models\Account`

but as `frontend\models\Orders` doesn't exist `frontend\models\Customer::getOrdersClass()` will still output `common\models\Orders`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use full namespace like this :

```
use common\models\Account as A2;
public static function getAccountClass(){
     echo get_class(new A2());
}
```

or

```
public static function getAccountClass(){
    echo get_class(new common\models\Account());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "right" way to solve it. However you could do something like this

Add a component or a helper or even add it to the construct of your initial class( depends how much you need to use it ):

```
public static function getClass($class)
{
    if (class_exists('frontend' . '\\' . $class)) {
        return frontend . '\\' . $class;
    } else  {
        return $class;
    }
}
```

And then you just can do something like this

```
public static function getAccountClass(){
    return self::getClass(Account::class);
}
```